# Set multiple variables via $_GET from URL

Tags: php, get

I have a table that can be sorted by any column using GET.  I'm trying to make a second variable that determines sort order also using get.  My understanding is that I could make the address as follows:

```
mypage.php?sortorder=1&sorttype=up
```

Using this as my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['sortorder'])) {
    $sortorder = $_GET['sortorder'];
}
if (isset($_GET['sorttype'])) {
    $sorttype = $_GET['sorttype'];
}
if ($sorttype = 'up') {
    $sortby = SORT_ASC;
}
else {
    $sortby = SORT_DESC;
}
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong?  The `GET` for sort type is ignored, selecting the 'else' value every time.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. PS: `=` and `==` are different operators

Comment: and the question would be?

Answer (score 1):

`if ($sorttype = 'up')` should be `if ($sorttype == 'up')` (note the double equals sign).